# Store data on the device permanently

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to store data on a device permanently so that it can be retrieved even if the user deletes the app completely? I have been using NSUserDefaults, but it seems it is not a permanent storage. I just want to store one simple string.

```
NSUserDefaults *userSettings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userSettings setObject:myString forKey:@"userSettings"];
[userSettings synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save your string in Keychain of device. It will remain stored even if app gets deleted. It will remain in Keychain until user reset device.

Comment: Can you please kindly show an example?

Comment: https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore

Comment: In above link you can find detailed information how to store and get stored key and value from keychain